# get_data: key title not found in requested column

Tags: gnuplot

What does the following error mean in gnuplot.

```
get_data: key title not found in requested column
```

Seems like this error occurs due to some space, tab problem, because if I type the same data by hand in the data file, it doesn't occur, but If I generate the data, it occurs, although the data has exactly the same number of columns.

Comment: could you please add more details? does it happen in a script?

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same problem and it was because of the formatting of the input file. Make sure the number of lines is correct to begin with. For me, since I copied the data file from gnuplot github account, instead of 11 lines my vi editor copied it as 15 lines and I could not spot this problem because each line was long.

Answer (score 0):

This warning could be avoided by making sure to provide column names to all the columns in the data file. For example, for a data file like
             `MMC               SMC
    A       0.5723111021    0.4871628549
    B       0.6666981168    0.6819255992
    C       0.2744373558    0.2129806222
    D       0.7185714286    0.3357142857`

where there is no column name for the first column, this error occurs.